# Can I find the last time a MemoryCache item was accessed?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, objectcache

In a .NET 4 `MemoryCache`, is there a way to find when an item was last accessed?  I'm sure it's being tracked internally, since `CacheItemPolicy` has the `SlidingExpiration` property.  But I haven't been able to find anywhere to read it.

Big picture, I'm looking for a way to manually remove the oldest *n* entries from a cache.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seems to be possible to obtain this information from the MemoryCache. You will have to use a wrapper on your items with a member for last-access-time and update it whenever an item is accessed.